# Java TreeMap get min and max values

Tags: java

I have this kind of a TreeMap. How can i get minimum and maximum values for town temperature after i make some entries in `towns`? I do not copy the code where i fill in some values in `towns` because it works fine.

```
Map<String, Town> towns = new TreeMap<>();
```

The Town.class is like this.

```
public class Town {

private int temperature;
private int rainfall;
private int windPower;
private Downwind downwind;

public Town(int temperature, int rainfall, int windPower, Downwind downwind) {
    this.temperature = temperature;
    this.rainfall = rainfall;
    this.windPower = windPower;
    this.downwind = downwind;
}

public int getTemperature() {
    return temperature;
}

public void setTemperature(int temperature) {
    this.temperature = temperature;
}

public int getRainfall() {
    return rainfall;
}

public void setRainfall(int rainfall) {
    this.rainfall = rainfall;
}

public int getWindPower() {
    return windPower;
}

public void setWindPower(int windPower) {
    this.windPower = windPower;
}

public Downwind getDownwind() {
    return downwind;
}

public void setDownwind(Downwind downwind) {
    this.downwind = downwind;
}
```

Comment: Do you just want to do this once, or many times?  (Assuming it's homework; do you need to get the value once, ever, or many many times?)

Comment: @Dean J I need it just one time.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest:

```
Optional<Town> maybeMinTown = towns.values().stream()
.min(Comparator.comparing(Town::getTemperature));

Town minTown = maybeMinTown.get(); // throws NoSuchElementException when towns map is empty
```

the same for `max` - you only need to use `max` instead of `min`.

UPDATE

To get **just** temperature you can `map` `Town` to temperature and then call `min`/`max`:

```
final OptionalInt min = towns.values().stream()
.mapToInt(Town::getTemperature)
.min();

min.getAsInt(); // or you can call min.orElseGet(some_lowest_value)
```

`OptionalInt` is the same for `int` what `Optional<Town>` is for `Town`.

Comment: When i print the code from your answer i get Optional[com.wcond.model.Town@682a0b20] ? How to fix this ?

Comment: You can simply call `Optional#get`. The whole idea behind `Optional`s is explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). Simply saying this is just placeholder which can have some value or not. In you case `Optional.empty()` is returned when map is empty :-)

Comment: Of course watch - if you call `.get()` on `Optional.empty()` object then `NoSuchElementException` is raised.

Comment: I do not understand it. Please give an example.

Comment: I updated my answer above, are you satisfied right now?

Comment: Now it is more clear but again i get the reference -  com.wcond.model.Town@682a0b20

Comment: Oh, sure. I haven't noticed that you would like get lowest/highest temparature. Then this is even easier but requires some knowledge about [streams api](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html). Please see my updated answer

Comment: Now it works but it get max and min values from all entries (temperature, rainfall, windPower, downWind)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not in Java 8, you have to order the Map by value to achieve that, maybe something like this

```
public static Map<String, Town> sortByValues(final Map<String, Town> map) {
    Comparator<String> valueComparator =  new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String k1, String k2) {
            if (map.get(k1).getTemperature() < map.get(k2).getTemperature()) {
                return 1;
            } else if (map.get(k1).getTemperature() == map.get(k2).getTemperature()) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    };
    Map<String, Town> sortedByValues = new TreeMap<String, Town>(valueComparator);
    sortedByValues.putAll(map);
    return sortedByValues;
}
```

When you create your TreeMap, pass an instance of this comparator class

```
towns = sortByValues(towns);
```

After that, you will have the maximun value at position 0 and the minimun in the last element.

**UPDATE**

Change the code in order to compile.

Comment: This can't work - how do you want to instantiate `TreeMap` with `Comparator` which compares whole entry instead of key? Maps work only on keys, values are just stored in the appropriate position in memory computed basing on keys. Or maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Yep, I am seeing that right now in eclipse... Thanks for point it out